# Assigning text to more than one textbox

Tags: c#

I am trying to get one button which inputs a specific character into two different text boxes, the code I am using only get me to input into one text box.

```
private void btn9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtBox1.Text = txtBox1.Text + btn9.Text;
}
```

I want to be able to have `btn9_Click` also work for what would be perceived as:

```
private void btn9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtBox2.Text = txtBox2.Text + btn9.Text;
}
```

Comment: You know you can have more than one line of code in a method, right?

Answer (score 1):

Just put both lines of code into the same Button Click Handler function

```
private void btn9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtBox1.Text = txtBox1.Text + btn9.Text;
    txtBox2.Text = txtBox2.Text + btn9.Text;
}
```

In fact, you can have hundreds of lines of code within a function. Usually it is best to keep it under 100 for readability.

## **Update 2**

To get the button to assign text to whichever function most recently had focus

This solution uses jquery to update the value of a Hidden Input whenever a textbox is focused (receives user attention). The solution uses ClientIDMode="Static" so that jquery is able to reference the proper elements.

In your ASPX page header, add a script tag to apply our Jquery

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $("#TextBox1").focus(function () {
    $('#MyHiddenInput').val('TextBox1');
  });

  $("#TextBox2").focus(function () {
    $('#MyHiddenInput').val('TextBox2');
  });
</script>
```

**In your ASPX page inside your form, add a hidden input with clientidmode=static**

```
<asp:HiddenField id="MyHiddenInput" runat="server" ClientIdMode="Static" Value="TextBox1" />
```

**Now, change your textboxes to have clientIdMode="Static"**

```
<asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" runat="server" clientIdMode="Static" />
<asp:TextBox id="TextBox2" runat="server" clientIdMode="Static" />
```

**Finally, in your codebehind, you can use code like this to figure out which textbox most recently had the focus

```
if ( MyHiddenInput.Value == "TextBox1" ){
  // Write to TextBox1
}else{
  // Write to TextBox2
}
```

**Or, if you're doing this in VB Forms, you can handle the [TextBox.GotFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus.aspx) event and set a string variable called LastTextboxFocus = "..." in place of the hidden field method above.**

Comment: Ok thanks everyone for the reply, though i have tried that and when i run the program and i do press btn9 the same thing appears in both text boxes. what i want is a way to press btn9 once and it appears in txtbox1 and highlight txtbox2 and be able to press btn9 once to have the same and/or different example btn8

Comment: See my update for an idea on how to debug your problem. My updated suggestion will try to put "ABC" into one textbox and "123" into the other textbox. If you succeed with this, you can probably start to get some idea about why the same text is going into both of your textboxes with your original code.

Comment: i see what your saying but i objective is to have an input button that only works when you highlight one of the two text boxes, with the way you have shown here when i press btn9_click it automatically fills in ABC and 123, i want it to be a selective process, where i select txtbox1 and press btn9 to get ABC/123 and also to select txtbox2 and press btn9 to get ABC/123

Comment: Can you explain it to me like I'm 6 years old? I'm not understanding this concept of highlighting a textbox and how that relates to the output

Comment: when i select push the button9 it comes up in box one, i want it to come up in box two, but not at the same time

Comment: So you want textbox1 to fill up only when ButtonA is pressed? And textbox2 will fill up only when ButtonB is pressed?

Comment: :) i want textbox1 to fill up when buttonA is pressed and textbox2 to be filled when buttonA is pressed. Trouble is i want to choose which textbox before buttonA is pressed and/or can be pressed.

Comment: So, you want the textbox that most recently had the user focus to receive the text output when the button is pressed?

Comment: See my update for how to accomplish this. You'll want to use client-side coding (jquery/javascript) to communicate to the code-behind which textbox most recently had focus.

Comment: sorry this not for  web page design its for a program i am trying to start

Comment: Ok, i added a bit. You can handle the Textbox.GotFocus event. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your event handler can have more than one line in it:

```
private void btn9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtBox1.Text = txtBox1.Text + btn9.Text;
    txtBox2.Text = txtBox2.Text + btn9.Text;
}
```

Comment: having more than one line is the issue the issue is what happens when i press that button it inputs the same information into the two text boxes at once i want an event that waits for me to highlight the text box before it decides which text box to input the information

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btn9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  txtBox1.Text = txtBox1.Text + btn9.Text;
  txtBox2.Text = txtBox2.Text + btn9.Text;
  txtBox3.Text = txtBox3.Text + btn9.Text;
  //for Any number textboxes, u can add text .......... 
}
```